# On the good set principle and sigma fields.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

Following *Probability and measure Theory* by Ash (2000).

let $\Omega$ be a set, let $C$ be a class of subsets of $\Omega$ and $A \subset \Omega$, we denote by $C \cap A$ the class $\{ B \cap A : B \in C \} $.
And the minimal sigma field over $C$ is denoted by $\sigma(C) = F$.

Ash wants to show that $B \cap A \in \sigma_A (C \cap A)$.

Let $L$ consist of those sets $B \in F$ s.t. $B \cap A \in \sigma_A (C \cap A)$.

Now Ash states that $C \subset L$. Why is this true?

Edit with original text:
[image]

Comment: You need additional assumptions for $B \cap A \in \sigma_A (C \cap A)$ to be true. Otherwise, a counterexample would be $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\varnothing$, $A=\{1,2\}$, and $B=\{1\}$.

Comment: When I get home I will copy the exact text to see if I made a mistake.

Comment: @HenningMakholm would you mind taking a look at my edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've omitted a lot of the text in you initial question -- perhaps you overlooked something there? And you also seem to be unfamiliar with the script font: $\mathscr S$ is a script S, not an L. (L would be $\mathscr L$).

Anyway, to the question: Why is $\mathscr C\subseteq \mathscr S$? Let's consider some $B\in\mathscr C$ and show that it is also in $\mathscr S$. For this we have to show that (1) $B\in \mathscr F$ and (2) $B\cap A\in\sigma_A(\mathscr C\cap A)$.

(1) $B\in \mathscr C$, and $\mathscr F=\sigma_\Omega(\mathscr C)$ by definition contains $\mathscr C$ as a subset. So $B\in\mathscr F$, as desired.

(2) Since $B\in \mathscr C$ we have $B\cap A\in\mathscr C\cap A$. By definition of $\sigma$, $\mathscr C\cap A$ is a subset of $\sigma_A(\mathscr C\cap A)$, so $B\cap A\in\sigma_A(\mathscr C\cap A)$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. I was confusing belonging to and forming  the sigma algebra, because$ B\in\mathscr F$ but $B$ is not necessarily a set that forms the sigma algebra  $\mathscr F$ correct?