# Abstract enunciation of the Good Set Principle in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am struggling with the ***Good Set Principle*** in Measure Theory, so is this rephrasing in the most abstract way ultimately correct?

> ***Good Set Principle***
>
> Let $(X, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. We want to prove that
>
> $$(\ast) \hspace{1cm} \forall B \ ( B \in \Sigma \Longrightarrow P(B) ) ,$$
>
> where $P(B)$ means that $B$ has the property $P$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{G}:= \{ X \mid X \in \Sigma, P(X) \ \}$. Hence, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to
>
> $$(\star) \hspace{1cm} \Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{G}. $$
>
> Assume additionally that $\Sigma = \sigma (\mathcal{A})$, where $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \wp (X)$. Thus, $(\star)$ is equivalent to
>
> $$ \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{G},$$
>
> which ultimately is what we have to prove, along with the fact that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

As always, thank you for you time.

---

**Edit for reference (after the answer)**

Just to clarify and make the overall question more perspicuous as a potential reference. As it is written above, the *Principle* is wrong. To make it correct simply:

> Assume $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and simply prove that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, your enunciation of the "Good Set Principle" in measure theory is not correct.

Let us look in details:

1. Let $P(x)$ means that "$x$ has property $P$".
   Let $\mathcal{G}:= \{ X \ | \ X \in \Sigma, P(X) \ \}$. Then it is true that
   $$(\ast) \hspace{1cm} \forall B \ ( B \in \Sigma \Longrightarrow P(B) ) $$
   is equivalent to
   $$(\star) \hspace{1cm} \Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{G} $$
   The proof is immediate.

So in this first step, your statement is correct.

2. **However**, since there is no restiction on the property $P$, we may have $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \wp (X)$, such that  $ \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ and $\sigma (\mathcal{A})\nsubseteq \mathcal{G}$. In fact, $\mathcal{G}$ don't need to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

So the principle, as you have enounced it, does not work.

**Example**: Let $X$ be $\mathbb{N}$, $\Sigma$ be $\wp (\mathbb{N})$. Take $P$ to be the property of having finite cardinality. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Then we have:

$(\ast)$ and $(\star)$ are both false (so equivalence is OK);

$ \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ but $\sigma (\mathcal{A})\nsubseteq \mathcal{G}$;

$\mathcal{G}$ is NOT a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Remark**: One way to correctly enunciate the Good Set Principle in measure theory is:

> Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space.  Suppose we want to prove that, for all $A\in \Sigma$, $A$ has property $P$ (which we will write $P(A)$). Then we can prove it by proving the three conditions:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{G}:= \{ X \ | \ X \in \Sigma, P(X) \ \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. (Note that it is actually a condition on $P$);
> 2. There is $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \wp (X)$, such that $\Sigma=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$;
> 3. $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{G}$.
>
> (if the three conditions hold, then $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{G}$)

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I find the answer a bit cryptic, in that it is another enunciation that does not address my first problem, namely if *my* enunciation is correct.

Comment: @Kolmin Please, check if it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks, this does sound more precise, but it leaves my with a strong doubt concerning your answer. Indeed, if I take a random book from my shelf (take for example Ash's "Probability and Measure"), it is said that the class of *good sets* $\mathcal{G}$ forms a $\sigma$-algebra. Here you can find a text with the page I am referring to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221175/on-the-good-set-principle-and-sigma-fields.

Comment: @Kolmin The error in your statement is that you need to *assume* that $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  That does not follow from the things you assumed.  If you add the assumption that $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then your induction principle becomes correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the missing point.

Comment: @Kolmin Actually,  when applying the principle, you must prove that $P$ makes $\mathcal{G}$ a $\sigma$-algebra.  This one of the conditions to apply the principle.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro: Could you please elaborate? Indeed, if I have to assume that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathcal{G}$ is defined as the class of sets that have property $P$, why should I *prove* your statement? Actually, I don't understand it.

Comment: Btw, now I am really starting to get confused. Looking on a book, I found that we have to show that $\mathcal{G}$ posses the property of a $\sigma$-algebra, but if we have to show it, how does it come that we have assumed it?! It does not make much sense to show something that we know applies because we assumed it...

Comment: @Kolmin $\mathcal{G}$ being a $\sigma$-algebra is one of the CONDITIONS  to apply the principle.  So to apply the principle you must prove that this condition is fulfilled.   On the other hand, when just enunciating the principle, you must just state, as a  condition, that  $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.   So, when you are just enunciating the principle you just require (in other words: "assume", as a condition) that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is clear.